# unable to pass app object to my class upcoming - error: app is not defined nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am unable to pass app object to my class upcoming .
it error - app is not defined
I want to pass express object into another class

Node.Js

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyparser.json());       
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Express server is runnig at port no : 3000'));
    
var UpComing = require('./Api/APIUpComingModels');
const Obj = new UpComing(app , mysqlConnection);
// var Obj = new UpComing(app , mysqlConnection);
Obj.Get();
```

APIUpComingModels.Js

```
class UpComing {

    constructor(app , mysqlConnection) {
        this.app = app;
        this.mysqlConnection = mysqlConnection;
    }

    Get(){
        app.get('/employeees', (req, res) => {
            mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM Employee', (err, rows, fields) => {
                if (!err)
                    res.send(rows);
                else
                    console.log(err);
            })
        });
    }
}
module.exports = UpComing
```

Comment: Please stop writing things in ALL CAPS

Comment: You are saying you are 'unable to', but you are doing this in your code. Can you explain the actual symptoms of your problem?

Comment: i unable to use app in APIUpComingModels.Js class   app.get

Comment: when i run this code it says  . app is not defined

Comment: Ok, for future questions you should consider sharing all these details and exact error messages in your questions. Don't make us guess!

Answer (score 0):

In your `Get()` method, you need to refer to `app` and `mysqlConnection` by prepending both with `this.`, so:

```
this.app
this.mysqlConnection
```